# choosing which domain account to use for sending email

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have code for sending email to clients.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
MailMessage Message = new MailMessage("From", "To", "Subject", "Body");
Client.Send(Message);
```

With following in App.config.

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="support@MyDomain1.com">
        <network host="smtp.MyDomain1.com" port="111" userName="abc" password="helloPassword1" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="support@MyDomain2.com">
        <network host="smtp.MyDomain2.com" port="222" userName="xyz" password="helloPassword2" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Problem is that in my code how can I differentiate which mailsetting to use for a given mail, meaning when I want to send mail from MyDomain1 account vs MyDomain2 account

Comment: Is the address you're sending from always one of the two there in the config?

Comment: Yes, At least at this point, its the same.

Comment: I believe this could help you ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363038/setting-multiple-smtp-settings-in-web-config

Comment: Yeah it helps for sure. Not sure how can I mark your comment as answer :)

Comment: @walther - why not post as an answer so imak can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one thread that contains the explanation how to achieve this.

[Setting multiple SMTP settings in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363038/setting-multiple-smtp-settings-in-web-config)

Wanted originally to post it as an answer, but the system automatically converted it into a comment. Seems I have to write longer messages.

Glad it helped :)