# multiple SMTP details used in Web.Config in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I have to used Multiple smtp detail in web.config file, may I used like this and how i can access different smtp for different purposes. I want to used first smtp for logging error. and second for successful mail to users.

Example

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
   <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="test@gmail.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="test@gmail.com" password="test"/>
  </smtp>

 <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="tes2t@gmail.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="tes2t@gmail.com" password="test2"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

How i can use first smtp for logging and second smtp for success msgs.

Comment: As far as I know, the above is **not** valid configuration. You can't have multiple `<smtp>` sections. I suspect that the application will crash with the above.

Comment: Any other way to access Multiple smtp concept

Comment: There are several ways to do this - from writing your own config section to using multiple `appSetting` entries.

Answer (score 0):

You must define multiple section based on `System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection` type.

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363038/setting-multiple-smtp-settings-in-web-config?answertab=votes#tab-top)